# Selecting Similar columns from multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

My table structure is as follows:

```
Computer:
    id serial,
    sbeadminlogin text,
    sbeadminfirstname text,
    sbeadminlastname text

Server:
    id serial,
    sbeadminlogin text,
    sapadminfirstname text,
    sapadminlastname text
```

There is no relation between those tables however they have column `sbeadminlogin` which is named same in both. It is possible that the person who is administrator in `Server` table is also administrator of other device which is stored iin `computer` tables.

I would like to create list of all administrators(only unique rows) from those tables in one query. In order to do so I used:

```
(select distinct sbeadminlogin from computer)
union
(select distinct sbeadminlogin from server)
```

which works great until I wanted to add name and last name to be visible in the result like :

```
(select distinct sbeadminlogin, sbeadminfirstname || ' ' || sbeadminlastname from computer)
union
(select distinct sbeadminlogin, saeadminfirstname || ' ' || saeadminlastname from server)
```

I got the error saying that column `saeadminfirstname` does not exist.

Could anyone give me a hint how to prepare statement so I get unique logins, first and lastnames from both tables?

Comment: saEadminfirstname? Shouldn't that be saPadminfirstname? BTW: remove the distinct keywords; they are superfluous and can slow down the query.

Comment: the main case is that column name`sbeadminlogin ` is the same for both tables but columns for firstname and lastname are different :/

Comment: Well, you get the syntax error, because you had a typo in the column names. As to the data: So you have the same sbeadminlogin in both tables, but first and last name can be (slightly) different, so you would like to find all sbeadminlogin and just display one of their first and last names, yes?

Comment: yes that is correct. For computer i would like to display `sbeadminlogin` + `sbeadminfirstname sbeadminlastname` and for server  `sbeadminlogin` + `sapadminfirstname sapadminlastname`

Comment: I see you accepted georstef's answer. So it was really just the typo I mentioned. And you want all names, not just one. Okay, that's easier. I'm glad georstef's query works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that if you place the correct column names (with alias or not) it will work:

```
(select sbeadminlogin, sbeadminfirstname || ' ' || sbeadminlastname as adminname from computer)
union
(select sbeadminlogin, sapadminfirstname || ' ' || sapadminlastname as adminname from server)
```

Example: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/58feb/1)

Comment: Well, I was close :) Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use  +' '+ to concatenate two columns and not ||.

ex.

(select distinct name+' '+city+' '+lastname from temp1)
union
(select distinct name+' '+city+' '+lastname from temp2)

Comment: `+` or `||` it does not matter. Main problem is that column names are different

Answer (score 0):

Try this query and check it :

```
(select distinct sbeadminlogin, sbeadminfirstname || ' ' || sbeadminlastname 
from computer)
union
(select distinct sbeadminlogin, sapadminfirstname || ' ' || sapadminlastname 
from server)
```

Comment: (select distinct sbeadminlogin, sbeadminfirstname || ' ' || sbeadminlastname from computer) union (select distinct sbeadminlogin, sapadminfirstname || ' ' || sapadminlastname from server)